# Easy way to track a simple input field ?

Tags: input, onclick, submit

I'm really new to this website coding stuff, so any help is welcome.

I think my problem is a very basic one, but it seems hard to find the exact thing I'm looking for.

**What I need :**

First of, a little explanation what I'm trying to build and why.

Soon my girlfriend and I will be going long distance for a significant amount of time. So I wanted to create something like a little, daily calendar she can access with a daily code which leads her to a webpage with a picture/text/video/whatever.

So far so good - managed to get this far with a website. But since those codes will be randomly pulled and entered, I have no idea which code was "used" that day.

What I'm looking for, is a very simple way to keep track of the inputs.

Since I'm not really sure how to go about it, it's hard to find something on my own

**Where I'm at:**

I have a site which only consists of a background, an input field and a button to submit that input.

That input then gets basically added to the website link to redirect to a subpage.

It looks like this currently :

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" id="code"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Enter" onclick="javascript:location.href='https://www.placeholderlink.com/' + getElementById('code').value + '.html' " />
```

So my question in the end would be :

How can I add a quick and easy way to keep track of the codes that have been input on the website ?